# Specify repeated expression in gitlab regex

Tags: regex, gitlab

How do you specify a repeated expression in a regular expression in gitlab?  More generally, where is the gitlab regex syntax specified?  All I could find was a few examples at https://gitlab.str.corp/help/user/packages/container_registry/index#regex-pattern-examples, which probably covers 95% of what users want, but not my case.

I am trying to write an image cleanup policy, where I need to specify a regex that matches image tags to delete.  Our repo has two types of image tags:

- version tags, which look like 1.2.3
- commit tags, which look like abcdef1234567890abcdef123456789087654321 (a 40 digit id)

I want something that matches the commit tag.  But depending on the regex version, that might be `.{40}` or `.\{40\}` or possibly one of those with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitLab uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) with Ruby's [regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Regexp.html) to match the provided parameters. In the source code for GitLab, you can see the current [regexp implementation here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/61335b6bcf6c5a4aff098c081451a9a744b65b15/lib/gitlab/untrusted_regexp.rb#L13) and its [usage in registry cleanup](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/61335b6bcf6c5a4aff098c081451a9a744b65b15/app/services/projects/container_repository/cleanup_tags_service.rb#L69-77).

Match tags in the `1.2.3` format:

```
\d+\.\d+\.\d+
```

Match tags with exactly 40 alphanumeric characters:

```
[A-z0-9]{40}
```

Comment: So documented in source code?

Comment: @TroyDaniels it's also in the [API documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#delete-registry-repository-tags-in-bulk). For example, the `name_regex` parameter is defined: "The [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) regex of the name to delete."

Comment: I failed to find that part of the documentation.  Is that on the page I linked to but didn't see, or a different page?  If it's a different page, can you post a link to that page?